# Spring WebClient's bodyToMono function returns null when mapping List of objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have implemented 2 services:

- `auth-service` which defines a REST endpoint that returns **username** and `List<GrantedAuthority>` if the token is valid
- `gateway-service` which calls **auth-service** on each request

The problem I have is that `List<GrantedAuthority>` that is returend to `gateway-service` is always null.

**AUTH-SERVICE:**

The `auth-controller` which constructs the data is very simple:

```
@Autowired
private final JdbcDaoImpl service;

@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<ConnValidationResponse> get(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = (String) request.getAttribute("username");
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) request.getAttribute("authorities");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(ConnValidationResponse.builder().status("OK").methodType(HttpMethod.GET.name())
            .username(username).authorities(grantedAuthorities)
            .isAuthenticated(true).build());
}

@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
public static class ConnValidationResponse {
    private String status;
    private boolean isAuthenticated;
    private String methodType;
    private String username;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
}
```

The JSON which is constructed in the `ResponseEntity` contains the correct values for authorities:

[Object on the auth-service side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR7Bo.png)

**GATEWAY-SERVICE:**

Then I have a simple filter on the `gateway-service` side:

```
@Autowired
WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

public AuthTokenFilter() {
    super(Config.class);
}

@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return ((exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

        if (!request.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
            return onFailure(exchange);
        }

        String authToken = Objects.requireNonNull(request.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).get(0);

        return webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri("lb://auth-service/auth")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authToken)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ConnValidationResponse.class)
                .map(response -> {
                    exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("username", response.getUsername());
                    exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("authorities", response.getAuthorities().stream()
                            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).reduce("", (a, b) -> a + "," + b));

                    return exchange;
                }).flatMap(chain::filter).onErrorResume(error -> onFailure(exchange));
    });
}
```

The `ConnValidationResponse` class on the `gateway-service` side is duplicated (I didn't want to make a reference to `auth-service` because it has a **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency.):

```
@ToString
@Data
public class ConnValidationResponse {
    private String status;
    private boolean isAuthenticated;
    private String methodType;
    private String username;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
}
```

Unfortunatelly the response from `auth-service` in `gateway-service` does not correctly map `List<GrantedAuthority>`

[Response in gateway-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwpiw.png)

Without this list of authorities I can not create authentication / authorization in my businesss logic services. Could this be related to MediaType and deserialization problems?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of hours I managed to get it to work. I'll share the solution in case someone stumbles upon the same problem.

I only needed to update the `gateway-service`:

1. Inside `ConnValidationResponse` I replaced `List<GrantedAuthority>` **->** `List<Authorities>`

```
@ToString
@Data
public class ConnValidationResponse {
    private String status;
    private boolean isAuthenticated;
    private String methodType;
    private String username;
    private List<Authorities> authorities;
}
```

2. add `Authorities` class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Authorities {
    private String authority;
}
```

3. Update `GatewayFilter` map

```
exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("authorities", response.getAuthorities().stream()
                                .map(Authorities::getAuthority).reduce("", (a, b) -> a + "," + b));
```